# Roulette wheel animation with dynamic data from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a roulette wheel that spins in 2 phases

1) When user clicks on spin button, it simply goes into infinite rotation till the data comes from the server.

2) When data arrives, it simply rotates by the angle as fetched from server.

We are fetching data from server because it contains some sensitive information we do not want to send to the client.

The problem I face is that the transition from 1) to 2) is not seamless. The spinner unexpectedly stops for random amount of time and then starts 2) (Finite rotation).

Here is my js fiddle that is the simplest replication of the scenario https://jsfiddle.net/ej2c5k7z/6/

The html:

```
<div id="spinning"  style="background-color: red; display: inline-block">
  abcdefghijkl
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
let element = $("#spinning");

// Simulate random interval for data being fetched from server
let randomIntervalSeconds = Math.random()*10;
console.log(randomIntervalSeconds);
// TODO: keep rotating the element for randomIntervalSeconds
// I used below code along with setInterval with 1001 ms interval
let intervalKey = setInterval(function(){
    element.css({"transform": "rotate(" + 360 + "deg)", "transition-duration": 1 + "s"});
},1001)


setTimeout(function(){
    // Simulate data arrived callback.
  clearInterval(intervalKey);
    element.css({"transform": "rotate(" + (360+48) + "deg)", "transition-duration": 1 + "s"});

}, randomIntervalSeconds*1000)
```

I just wonder if it is at all possible to keep the spinner(or any div) rotating infinitely till data arrives and **seamlessly** transition to a finite rotation?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not exactly what you are looking for but maybe it can inspire you over the goal line. I tried giving your div a class that makes it always spin and then after the timeout expires, I remove the spinning animation and rotate the div by the necessary amount of degrees. it seems like it "snaps" into place a little too much and I haven't (yet?) figured out how to get around that, but I'll try some more tomorrow.

```js
let element = $("#spinning");

// Simulate random interval for data being fetched from server
let randomIntervalSeconds = Math.random()*10;
console.log(randomIntervalSeconds);
// TODO: keep rotating the element for randomIntervalSeconds
// I used below code along with setInterval with 1001 ms interval



setTimeout(function(){
    // Simulate data arrived callback.
  element.removeClass("go");
    element.css({"transform": "rotateZ(" + (360+48) + "deg)", "transition-duration": 1.5 + "s"});

}, randomIntervalSeconds*1000)
```

```css
#spinning {
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 50px;
}
.go {
 animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes spin {
 from { transform: rotateZ(0deg) }
 to { transform: rotateZ(360deg) }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spinning" class="go">
  abcdefghijkl
</div>
```

Comment: I have already tried removing css animation classes. but this transition is too abrupt and looks unnatural.